# How to show interstitial ad on ontap() function in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
void _handleButtonClick() {
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
      _loadInterstitialAd();
    }
    else {
      print('Button clicked: $clickCount times');
    }
  }
void _loadInterstitialAd() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoadingAd = true;
    });

    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712', // Replace with your ad unit ID
      request: AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoadingAd = false;
            _showAd = true;
          });
          _interstitialAd = ad as InterstitialAd;
          _interstitialAd.show();
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoadingAd = false;
          });
          print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
        },
      ),
    );
  }



GestureDetector(
                          onTap: ()
                          {
                       _handleButtonClick();
                       Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const TwitterQRCodeGeneratorPage(),
                                  ),
                                );
}
,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'asset/Twitter.png',
                            width: 110,
                            height: 110,
                          ),
                        ),
```

I want to show when the user click on Twitter generator page the circular progress indicator will appear for some seconds so that user will know the ad is going to appear then the interstitial ad will appear .and when the user click on cross button the add will remove and twitter generator page will appear and this progress indictor will show when ad before ad appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool _isLoadingAd = false;
InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;

void _handleButtonClick() {
  clickCount++;
  if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
    _loadInterstitialAd();
  } else {
    print('Button clicked: $clickCount times');
  }
}

void _loadInterstitialAd() async {
  setState(() {
    _isLoadingAd = true;
  });

  InterstitialAd.load(
    adUnitId: id,`enter code here`
    request: AdRequest(),
    adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
      onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoadingAd = false;
          _interstitialAd = ad as InterstitialAd;
        });

        // ad will show when its loaded
        _interstitialAd?.show();
      },
      onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoadingAd = false;
        });
        print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
      },
    ),
  );
}

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    _handleButtonClick();
    if (_isLoadingAd) {
     //  here is the circular progress indicator while the ad is loading
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const TwitterQRCodeGeneratorPage(),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
  child: Image.asset(
    'asset/Twitter.png',
    width: 110,
    height: 110,
  ),
),
```

in my case it worked but i am not sure this is exactly what you want but let me know if you need help in this!

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?